# System.ArgumentException when adding information to the database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I keep having an error every time I try to add information to my database tables.

```
Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <JHK> in KEY TAG Column.  Expected type is Int32.
```

This is my code so far.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class add_new_key_window

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub add_new_key_window_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'saveRecord()
    management_window.RKM_SystemTableAdapter.Insert(Me.TextBox1.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.TextBox3.Text, Me.TextBox4.Text, Me.TextBox5.Text, Me.TextBox6.Text, Me.RichTextBox1.Text)
    management_window.RKM_SystemTableAdapter.Fill(management_window.RKM_System_dataDataSet.RKM_System)
    clearTextboxes()
End Sub

'Public Sub saveRecord()
'    Dim cn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\RKM System data.accdb")
'    Dim str As String

'    Try
'        cn.Open()
'        Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [RKM System]([KEY TAG], LOCATION, [HOOK NO], [KEY TYPE], BRAND, SERIAL, [TAG COLOR], NOTES) " & _
'                                                      "VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','1','" & TextBox3.Text & _
'                                                      "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & _
'                                                      "','" & RichTextBox1.Text & "') ", cn)
'        str = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
'        MsgBox("The new record was inserted successfully!")

'    Catch ex As Exception
'        MsgBox("Error message: " & ex.Message)
'    End Try  
'    cn.Close()
'End Sub

Public Sub clearTextboxes()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value in textbox1.text into an integer - currently it is tring to store a string in an int32 field

For example an access database may have a field that is of type "Number" into which you have to put a number of some sort. You are trying to directly put the contents of the text box into this field which is NOT a number, it is a string. Therefore you need to "Cast" the data in the text box into the correct type using "int.Parse(textbox1.Text)" or similar.

Incidentally you should NEVER use inline statements when creating an sql query like this. Use SQL parameters instead otherwise you are opening yourself up to potential sql injection attacks.

eg (in c# not too well up on my vb!):

```
var cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (firstname, lastname) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname)");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (int)textbox1.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", textbox2.text);
```

For more info see

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Holly cow... I forgot to mention... I'm a very beginner. I know is much to ask to explain but I am passionate about coding and I want to learn. Is there any chance of explaining as you'd be explaining to someone who's a beginner? Many thanks for coming back this fast.

Comment: you might want to convert that to VB now before questions about syntax errors flow your way.  Also, you are adding TB1 twice, and OleDb doesnt actually use named parameters which can be misleading.

Comment: OK I didnt know OLEDB didnt use them (mainly because I have spent years workign with decent dbms's such as MYSQL and semi-decent ones like MSSQL - never done anything with Access although the lack of functionality doesnt surprise me)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub saveRecord()
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & 
                 myDbFileName)

    Dim SQL as String = "INSERT INTO [RKM System]([KEY TAG], LOCATION, [HOOK NO], 
             [KEY TYPE], BRAND, SERIAL, [TAG COLOR], NOTES) 
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
             ' ? = a place holder for a parameter to be added later

    Try
        cn.Open()

        Using cmd As New OleDBCommand(SQL, cn)
            ' add param values IN ORDER SPECIFIED
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox2.Text)
            ' etc
            ' number of AddWithValue lines must = number of "?" in SQL

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
         End Using            ' disposes of the OLEDbCOmmand object


        MessageBox.Show("The new record was inserted successfully!")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error message: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Parameters avoid SQL injection attacks (read up on this).

Since [KEY TAG] is an integer column in the DB, and TextBox1.Text is string (always), you need to use `Convert.ToInt32` to convert the value (since it is user input, you should actually use `Integer.TryParse` in case they entered "red" or "ziggy").

OleDB treats named parameters as simple place holders, so this can get you in trouble:

```
 Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName) 
            Values (@FName, @LName)"

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", TextBox1.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", TextBox2.Text)
```

TextBox1 will map to FirstName because it is the first column names in the SQL.